# How to say "turn around!" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, phrases, phrase-requests

How do you order someone to turn around in a direct and forceful manner, like the way a police officer or soldier would say? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> like the way a police officer or soldier would say?

How about...

「[[回]{まわ}れ[右]{みぎ}！](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8C%E5%8F%B3/)」?

or maybe something like...

> Biff: Just turn around, McFly, and walk away.
>   ビフ: [**回れ右だ**マクフライ。とっとと消えろ。](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFWiH07MPBg&feature=youtu.be&t=120)

Comment: I'm intrigued by the 右 part. Is there something culturally significant about turning right rather than left?

Comment: そ～ですねえ・・「回れ左」はないですね～。[プログレッシブ和英](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8C%E5%8F%B3/) で「回れ右」を引くと、`《米》About face!《英》About turn!` 、でも [アルク](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8C%E5%8F%B3) には `right-about-face` `right-about-turn` って書いてありますね。英語には "left-about-face!" "left-about-turn!" があるんでしょうか？

Comment: I think the 'right-about-face' in アルク is an overly literal translation. I've heard about-face many times in films (never in real life fortunately :-) ), but I don't think I've ever heard right-about-face. Although dictionary.com does have an entry for it (but not for left-about -face). We'd only expect to hear about-face in a military context though. It would be very unusual to hear it from a police officer.

Comment: なんか違うような気がしてきた・・

Answer (score 2):

You could literally just say 「後ろをむけ！」, but I'm not sure if this is what law enforcement or military would use.